# Can I use printf format when using log4cplus?

Tags: c, printf, log4cplus

Does log4cplus gives an API to print in C-Style / printf format?

Reason: I would like to use log4cplus in C code (in addition to C++) and don't want to prepare the string before hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the logging macros have an `FMT` variant that does what you expect:

```
LOG4CPLUS_WARN_FMT(logger, "Hello %s %d", "World", 1);
```

Compare/contrast with the "default" variant, which uses C++ streams:

```
LOG4CPLUS_WARN(logger, "Hello " << "World " << 1);
```

There's also an `_STR` variant which can be used to output an `std::string` if you have it ready (without paying for the overhead of a C++ string stream).

Comment: Where are these macros included? I couldn't find documentation about them

Answer (score 0):

[Matteo Italia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946702/341065) is correct. I only add that you should take a look at `log4cplus/clogger.h` header, if you intend to use log4cplus from C code. However, that header does not make the usual logging macros available. You would have to prepare your own macros or use the functions directly.